# how to achieve pagination with JavaScript, fetching from Django backend in SPA?

Tags: javascript

I have Single page application, one of my pages is all_posts which displays all the posts in the database, my other page is following users posts, which displays all the posts from the profiles the user is following - all using fetch from the backend (Django)

I have built pagination buttons in load_posts, but now if I want the same thing in the following posts page, Do I need to add a new variable following_current_page = 1 and do all the process again? any direction on how to implement this without repeating myself?

index.js

```
    let current_page = 1;
    // Method to display all the posts in the database.
    function load_posts(){
      document.querySelector('#page-view').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#load-profile').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#posts-view').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#show-posts').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#post-form').onsubmit = function() {
            compose_post();
        }
        fetch(`/posts/all_posts?page=${current_page}`) // url with that API
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(all_posts => {
            if (all_posts.total_posts > 10){
            const pagination_buttons = document.createElement('div');
            if(current_page > 1){
                const prev_button = document.createElement('button');
                prev_button.innerHTML = 'Prev'
                pagination_buttons.appendChild(prev_button);
            prev_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if(current_page <= all_posts.num_of_pages){
                    current_page--;
                    console.log(windows.history.)
                    load_posts();
                }
            });
            }
            const next_button = document.createElement('button');
            next_button.innerHTML += 'Next'
            pagination_buttons.appendChild(next_button);
            next_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if(current_page < all_posts.num_of_pages){
                    current_page++;
                    load_posts();
                }
            });
            pagination_buttons.classList.add('pagination_buttons');
            document.querySelector('#show-posts').appendChild(pagination_buttons);
            }
            all_posts.posts.forEach(function(post) { // loop to loop over each object
                build_post(post)
            });
        });
    document.querySelector('#show-posts').innerHTML = ""
    }

function load_following_users_posts(){
  document.querySelector('#page-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#load-profile').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#posts-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#show-posts').style.display = 'block';
    fetch(`/posts/following_users_posts`) // url with that API
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(following_posts => {
        following_posts.posts.forEach(function(post) { // loop to loop over each object
            build_post(post)
        });
    });
document.querySelector('#show-posts').innerHTML = ""
}
```

views.py

```
def show_all_web_posts(request):
    """
    Method to return all posts in the database.
    """
    all_web_posts = NewPost.objects.all()
    all_web_posts = all_web_posts.order_by("-date_added").all()
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(all_web_posts, 10)
    current_page_posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    posts_paginated = current_page_posts.object_list
    return JsonResponse({
        "num_of_pages": paginator.num_pages,
        "total_posts": all_web_posts.count(),
        "posts": [website_post.serialize() for website_post in posts_paginated]
     }, safe=False)

def display_following_profiles_posts(request):
    """
    Method to return the posts by the profiles that the currently logged in user is following.
    """
    current_user = request.user.username
    current_user = User.objects.get(username=current_user)
    current_user = Profile.objects.get(user=current_user)
    following_posts = []
    for user in current_user.following.all():
        for post in NewPost.objects.filter(poster=user.id):
            following_posts.append(post.serialize())
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(following_posts, 10)
    current_page_posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    following_posts_paginated = current_page_posts.object_list
    return JsonResponse({
        "posts": [post for post in following_posts_paginated]
    }, safe=False)
```

Comment: For pagination, you have few attributes page_count, current_page, total_display. You could create an element, and clear it on new page click and load it with new attribute. Because you're making an AJAX/Fetch request you don't need to reload the page or anything.

Comment: I'm reloading because my pagination is basically in the backend (I have edited the post with views.py), so basically I need to fetch again every time I click on the "Next" post with the new page number, to get the next page posts, or maybe I understand this wrong?

Comment: It is best not to ask "is it possible to do X in Y", unless a simple "yes" or "no" is a good enough answer. Instead, ask "how do I achieve X in Y?", or simply describe "Stuck when doing X in Y"

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have changed the title, Thanks!

Comment: Seems obvious you just need to write up a JSON Response for when users ask for it. You can provide full query to them (searched each time or cached) or pull portions of it based on the GET your server receives?

Comment: That's what I have on my views.py method, it sends the next "10" posts every time the user asks for it using (fetch) in the JavaScript function, and I change the current_page number that's why I'm calling the function again because I need to show the next fetched data?, excuse me if I don't understand I'm still practicing this, but I've been stuck with this problem for over a week